# Why does React throw an error when exporting a function from one component to other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two react components Posts and Postform. Posts is a component that displays the list of posts fetched from an [api](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/). The Postform component is a form that creates a new post and then updates the Post component. I declared a function addPost() as global in Posts and bound it within the Posts constructor.
Then the addPost() method is exported from the Posts and is imported into the Postform component from where I want to update the state of the Posts component using the imported addPost() method

However I receive an error stating that this is invalid inside of addPost() in the Post component
This process of updating a sibling from another sibling is taken from this [blog post](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1215984/Update-State-of-a-Component-from-Another-in-React)

I am including both the components' code for reference.

This is Posts.js i.e.,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export function addPost(posts){
  this.setState({ posts });
}

export default class Posts extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    }
   this.getPosts = this.getPosts.bind(this);
   addPost = addPost.bind(this);
  }

  getPosts(posts) {
    this.setState({ posts, })
    console.log(this.state);
  }


  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(posts => this.getPosts(posts));

  }

  render() {
    const posts = this.state.posts;
    const postList = posts.map(post => {
      return (
        <div key={post.id}>
          <div>ID: {post.id}</div>
          <br />
          <div>{post.title}</div>
          <br />
          <div>{post.body}</div>
          <hr />
        </div>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Posts</h1>
        <hr />
        {postList}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is Postform.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import  addPost  from './Posts.js';

export default class Postform extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      body : '',
    }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    })
  }


  onSubmit(event) {
    const post = {
      title: this.state.title,
      body : this.state.body
    }
    //this is going to start a fetch process to post the new post to the database
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(post),
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => addPost({data}));

    event.preventDefault();

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ADD POST</h1>   
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.onChange} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Body</label>
            <textarea name="body" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.body} />
          </div> 
          <br />
          <button type="submit">ADD</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these lines:

```
export function addPost(posts){
  this.setState({ posts });
}
```

This will not work as there is no concept of `this` outside of the `Post` class. You should have a function in the parent component (`Postform`) and update the props this way.

Comment: I referred to the blog post I mentioned in the question , where sibling to sibling communication is shown to be possible by creating a function outside of a class and binding it within the class's constructor.
Please reassure that this is an incorrect way of implementing sibling to sibling communication. Here's the link
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1215984/Update-State-of-a-Component-from-Another-in-React